# How to make tmux's reaction faster?

Tags: tmux

I use tmux and find one problem of it.
For example, I make 2 panes within 1 window under tmux. 
In one pane, I compile Linux kernel and as you know it will output a lot of message there. 
During the compilation, in another pane of tmux, when I tried to input some command, it will react very slow.
How to solve this?
Thanks!

BR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With two panes, `tmux` has to update two portions of the screen at once. My suggestion is to let the compile running in a separate window, so that `tmux` doesn't need to render so much output to the visible screen, and configure some sort of monitor on the compile window so you will be notified when it is finished.

Comment: So there's no split vertical split screen option for flow control?

Answer (score 4):

As chepner says, tmux has to send a lot more characters to update a bigger part of the screen. In my case, enabling ssh compression reduced this kind of slowness quite a lot. You can give it a try with:

```
ssh -C user@host
```

or put `Compression yes` into your `~/.ssh/config` to make it permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Question asked in June.. 2012?! ^^
If you are using X11, try a different terminal. Besides those based on xterm there are KDE's konsole and it's variants (like yakuake drop-down terminal) and GNOME's VTE and offsprings (like guake drop-down terminal :)), display update speed can be very different.
Furthermore, a rate limiting feature was implemented in march which will be in the 1.7 release out soon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am trying yakuake, very good and can replace tmuxx.

Comment: @Tom: even though I mentioned yakuake before guake, having used both extensively with tmux, for me it is guake because:

Comment: - it doesn't make your browser crash while typing a comment